# How to use 3-drive IDE cable?

Tags: pata, ide-cable

I saw a [3-drive IDE cable](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10227&cs_id=1022700&p_id=1245&seq=1&format=2) at Monoprice but I've never seen this  before. How would you set the jumpers on the drives and their positions to use this cable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PATA IDE supports 2 drives per channel max. So even if you have the extra drop you can't use it.  This cable would probably work with only two drives attached though, unless there's something (else) weird about this cable. :)

The cable you linked to just happens to be a 40-pin ribbon cable with 4 drops, and these people have mistakenly labeled it as an "IDE" cable.  There's more uses for ribbon cables than just IDE in a standard PC, and you can get them in many different wire/drop count combinations from electronic supply companies.

Answer (score 0):

The cable in the link is over a yard long.  Some old full tower/server chassis had really long distances between the motherboard's IDE connector and the drive bays.  This cable would span those distances.